# ZipArchive not found when using php-worker form laradock

Tags: php, laravel, docker, supervisord, laradock

Basically I've [this package](https://github.com/ludo237/laravel-logs-manager) which internally uses [ZipArchive](https://github.com/ludo237/laravel-logs-manager/blob/master/src/Console/ArchiveCommand.php#L63)

I've set up the flag `PHP_FPM_INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE=true` for my php-fpm container

The package works as expected when I launch `php artisan log:archive` command inside my `workspace` container but if I try to setup Horizon on `php-worker` something awful happens, basically as soon as I start php-worker `docker-compose up -d php-worker` with the following configuration for supervisor:

```
[program:laravel-horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /var/www/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/storage/logs/horizon.log


[program:laravel-queue-work]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02da
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/storage/logs/queue-work.log
```

Both `queue-work.log` and `horizon.log` are filled with a **Class ZipArchive not found in [ArchiveCommand.php](https://github.com/ludo237/laravel-logs-manager/blob/master/src/Console/ArchiveCommand.php#L63)**

Of course removing the package from the dependencies solves the problem but it should not be a solution since ZipArchive is installed and the package works as expected inside `workspace`

What am I missing?

---

#### Expected behavior:

Container php-worker should start without prompting for the exception `Class ZipArchive not found in ...`

---

#### Reproduce:

- Fresh install of laravel
- Add `"ludo237/laravel-logs-manager": "^1.0",` as dependency
- Build `workspace` and `php-fpm` with `PHP_FPM_INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE=true`
- Test the command excepted behavior in `workspace`
- Create a `php-worker` container with the supervisor configuration above
- Test the unexpected behavior inside the logs

Related [issue on Github](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1874)

Answer (score 1):

PHP-FPM container and PHP-WORKER container is not the same you need to install the package to PHP-WORKER. ( php-worker is where supervisor is running )